# Index Error is occurring

Tags: python

I am getting "INDEXERROR: list index out of range" problem.

It does not occur for the similar code that I wrote.

I indicate the error line with ------- sign -------.

.
.
.
.
.
.
.

```
#import json


result = {}

#declare variables
count = -1
category = None
paragraph = None

#list of files
file_lists = ["sc.txt" ] 


for file in file_lists:
#read line 
for line in open(file,'r').readlines():
    pieces = line.split('\t')


    #if category is empty assign 'category' from line 1 
    if (category == None):
        category = pieces[0]

    #if starts with 'Question' skip
    elif (pieces[0].startswith('Question')):
        continue

    #if------ ERROR OCCURS RIGHT BELOW THIS LINE !!!!!------------
    elif ((pieces[0] != '') and (pieces[1] == '')):
        paragraph = pieces[0]

    #add incorrect to the dict
    elif ((pieces[0] != '') and (pieces[1] != '')):
        count += 1
        result[count] = {'Category': category,
             'Question': paragraph,
             'Given_sen': pieces[0],
             'Incorrect':[pieces[1]],
             'Correct': pieces[2],
             'Rule': pieces[3]
            }
    elif (pieces[0].startswith('')):
        result[count]['Incorrect'].append(pieces[1])
```

Comment: One of the lines doesn't have a tab.

Comment: Most likely one of your lines contains no tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add try except to your code as below and track which line broke your code

```
for line in open(file,'r').readlines():
    try:
        pieces = line.split('\t')
        ...

    except IndexError as ie:
        print ie
```

Alternatively, if all your lines are always split to same length of elements. you can check `len(pieces)`  If the length is not equal to the expected length value, use `continue` to ignore the rest code.